# attachment files not showing in the saved list

Tags: office-365

I have added an attachment file in Sharepoint 365 but it is not showing in the saved list. I can see the file in the edit format of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that attachments are added to the list view.

If you want to be able to see the names of the attachments, use the [SharePoint 2013/online Attachment Viewer Enhancement](https://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2014/11/17/sharepoint-2013online-attachment-viewer-enhancement/).